# Most common cassandra cql commands

Tags: cassandra

I am looking at exploring optimization of cassandra for a limited set of commands. For that I wanted to know which among SELECT,  INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE & BATCH is the CQL command with highest frequency of use in realtime systems. Any pointers and thoughts on this would be great help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as common cql commands, it all depends for which use case cassandra is deployed.

So Instead of optimizing commands  you could go for Use Case based optimization:

Eg: UseCase: Write oriented Workload:
Optimize Insert and Update commands.